# Microsoft Access, filtering specific data but still allow others through

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a 2 columns, 1 for salesperson and another for products.

Say we sell 5 products, but Bob(Salesperson) only gets extra creds for selling 2 specific ones (A and B).

Right now if I enter A and B as a Criteria, it will also filter only those 2 products for other salesperson. Is there an Iif I can use to filter only Bob but not filter for the others?

Comment: Would something like Iif([Salesperson]="B", "A" Or "B",*) be able to solve it? I don't understand wildcards much.

Answer (score 1):

No wildcards are needed here. Just two conditions.

```
WHERE Product IN("A", "B") OR SalesPerson <> "Bob"
```

This selects both products A and B for Bob, and everything for the rest.

Comment: Nope, read it again. Either the products are in `A, B`, or the person is _not_ Bob. That leaves only A and B for Bob, and everything for everyone else.